Old mechanical chime buzzing when video doorbell installed
Last week I replaced my doorbell button with the Wyze Video Doorbell Duo, which runs on 10-24V AC. My existing doorbell transformer was 10V so I reckoned it would work fine. However, the 1950s-era mechanical chime immediately began buzzing when I installed the video doorbell (without the doorbell being pressed), and the chime would spontaneously do a full ring every hour or so, despite the doorbell not being touched.
I swapped the transformer to a 16V AC unit, since I read online that by increasing the voltage one is therefore decreasing the current. Still, the same buzzing.
Swapped transformer to 24V AC...same buzzing!
I understand why this is happening- a small amount of current (~0.1A) is flowing through the circuit to power the video doorbell, and thus causing the chime's solenoids to vibrate. Some say to install a resistor.
How to resolve this?

Did you get a "Wyze Chime Controller" and wire it in according to its instructions? You don't mention that...

it's normal ... the video unit draws current at all times... that current flows through the chime, which activates the chime

Did you read any of the instructions?

Thanks all. I saw Ecnerwal's response and realized the instructions I received in the box and in the app were far simpler than what was on Wyze's website.
Furthermore, I saw this detail on Wyze's website:
"Instead of using Wyze Wi-Fi Chime included with your Wyze Duo Cam Doorbell, you can opt to use your home's built-in chime. It will require a Wyze Chime Controller, which comes with the purchase of a Wyze Video Doorbell v2."
Pretty ridiculous that the Duo doesn't come with the chime controller.

I installed the jumper cable between the Front and Trans lugs on the doorbell chime. This fixed the buzzing by bypassing the chime. Thank you again all for pointing this detail out to me.

Instructions say, in part:

Follow the in-app instructions to use the jump wire to bypass your
existing chime*.

and:

*Though using your in-house chime is an option (requires a Wyze Chime Controller)

It sounds like that's not what you did. The chime controller apparently isolates the doorbell connection on the original chime from the loop current for the video doorbell, and then switches the new connection from it to the chime only when the doorbell is pressed.
Instructions for the chime controller.
